# form_for [@parent, @child] causes undefined method `parent_child_path' in Child#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So a user has many colleges (that they have attended), and a college belongs to a user. I call these colleges, college_profile as they are the college attribute of a user's profile.

I am running into the problem when trying to generate a new college. My controller for the college at the moment is very simple:

```
def new
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @college = current_user.college_profile.build if signed_in?
end
```

And the view equally as simple: (views/college_profiles/new.html.erb)

```
<%= form_for [@user, @college] do |f| %>
   <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
   <%= f.label :name %>
 <% end %>
```

And yet, for some reason I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in College_profiles#new

Showing .../app/views/college_profiles/new.html.erb where line #4 raised:

undefined method `user_college_profiles_path' for #<#<Class:0x5bf1b68>:0x673aef8>
```

As I am still learning Rails, I really don't even understand what this error is exactly referring to. A fair amount of Google-ing has given me no luck, or if the answer *is* out there I simply don't know enough to realize I was looking at it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

If it is relevant, seeing as we're talking about paths, here's an excerpt from my routes file:

```
resources :users, :only => [:index, :new, :create, :destroy, :update, :edit] do
  resources :college_profiles, :only => [:new, :create]
end
```

If any more info is needed, just let me know. Thanks!

Comment: in routes you have :college_profile, shouldn't be :college_profiles ?

Comment: @ismaelga Wow, that may have solved the problem right there.  I keep getting mixed up when to and when not to pluralize...

Comment: @ismaelga post that as the answer, so OP can accept :)

Comment: check Beerlington's answer. I solved the problem because the answer was already gave by him, I guess :) he just didn't realize.

Comment: Well the page loads now, but submitting the form gives a similar error: `undefined method 'college_profiles_path'` unless I specify the post url as stated below, but then I lose the form data. /confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing about `form_for` is that its URL is based on the model that you passed in. In your case, it's:

```
<%= form_for [@user, @college] do |f| %>
```

Rails automatically looks for `user_college_profiles_path` because you assigned `User` to `@user`, and `current_user.college_profile` to `@college`.

Fortunately, Rails provides a way to override the default URL the form will go to on submit:

```
<%= form_for([@user, @college], :url => your_custom_route_path) do |f| %>
```

All you need to do is create `your_custom_route` in your `routes.rb`

Source: [Ruby on Rails Guides: Rails Form Helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html)

Comment: Thanks! This seems to have gotten me past the error but... to be honest I'm not sure what url I should be giving it. I generated a named path to `College_Profile#create` but it didn't seem to carry over any of the form data. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the relationship of `User` and `CollegeProfile`? Is it one-to-many? Based on your edit, I think your problem has something to do with your models and routes instead of the form itself.

Comment: User has many Colleges, College belongs to User. Adding the custom url stopped the error but may have caused new problems - perhaps due to my models. I thought I could just hand the form off to the College_Profile create method, which tries to save the data.

Answer (score 0):

Rails is trying to create a path that will be used to post data from the form to your controller. The action that it's looking for is create, but you only have new defined in your routes. If your controller is called CollegeProfiles, then you will need to change your nested route to:

```
resources :college_profiles, :only => [:new, :create]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but that's not it. I added that in and it changed nothing. Besides, to my understanding, new is for initializing the new object and create is after you submit the form and save it. Either way, I gave it a shot but no luck

Comment: Did you restart your server? What do you get if you run rake routes?