# undefined method for 'parent_children_path'

Tags: forms, form-for

I'm quite new to rails and I'm still following the [tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#adding-a-second-model) on how to show and create associated records in the show view of a parent record. I'm trying to add a form that creates child records.

building/show.html.erb contains the following form:

```
<%= form_for([@building, @building.rooms.build]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :name %><br>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The model classes are already set up for the association using has_many and belongs_to.

BuildingsController has

```
def show
    @building = Building.find(params[:id])
    @room = Room.new
    @room.building_id = @building.id
end
```

RoomsController has

```
def new
  @room = building.rooms.new
end

def create
  @building = Building.find(params[:building_id])
  @room = @Building.rooms.create(room_params)
  redirect_to building_path(@building)
end
```

Im not sure what I miss but when I load a building record `/building/1` in browser, i get
`undefined method building_rooms_path`. I'm thinking it might be with my idiomatic use of form_for. I'm just copying it from the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Some possible answers can be found here: [form_for [@parent, @child] causes undefined method `parent_child_path' in Child#new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359071/form-for-parent-child-causes-undefined-method-parent-child-path-in-child)

But in my case, I found the solution when I checked routes.rb

```
resources :buildings
resources :rooms
```

It should have been

```
resources :buildings do
   resources :rooms
end
```